# Does the Church say that humans have two parts, ie mind and heart?

Tags: catholicism

In the Catechism ([2559](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/para/2559.htm)) we find:

> "Prayer is the raising of one's mind and heart to God or the requesting of good things from God."

I think this quote is from John Damascene.

Does the Church say that humans have two parts, i.e. mind and heart?

Answer (score 1):

**Does the Church say that humans have two parts, ie mind and heart?**

The Catholic Catechism (2559) states the following:

> "Prayer is the raising of one's mind and heart to God or the requesting of good things from God." But when we pray, do we speak from the height of our pride and will, or "out of the depths" of a humble and contrite heart? He who humbles himself will be exalted; humility is the foundation of prayer, Only when we humbly acknowledge that "we do not know how to pray as we ought," are we ready to receive freely the gift of prayer. "Man is a beggar before God."

This is not say to humans are made up of two part parts but rather it is an expression that infers we should raise our intellect towards God love God with our whole being (our heart).

Physically man is made up of many members: hands, head, legs, hearts and so forth. The Catholic Catechism is simply using an expression to convey a meaning.

We are encouraged to raise our mind and hearts to God...

There is a nuance to be understood here.

> **For just as the body is one and has many members**, and all the members of the body, though many, are one body, so it is with Christ. 13 For in one Spirit we were all baptized into one body—Jews or Greeks, slaves[a] or free—and all were made to drink of one Spirit. - [1 Corinthians 12:12-27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2012%3A12-27&version=ESV)

Comment: So mind and intellectus are synonyms?   Some speak of three powers of the soul and not two.   St Maximus said: “The soul has three powers: the intelligence (mind), the incensive power (heart) and appetitive (will).”  That seems a bit different from the thomistic tradirion